# ant script stops, waiting for input when run in background

Tags: bash, job-control

I'm running an ant (Java build tool) script on CentOS 5.5 that execs another java process. When I run the ant script in the background:

```
ant -f myfile.xml &> foo.out &
```

The forked process' state changes to stop and waits for input. As soon as I bring the process to the foreground  it starts again (no input required on my part)

This does not occur on other machines running the same OS, CentOS 5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. A little googling brought up this page:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#background

Looks like ant immediately tries to read from standard input, which causes the background process to suspend